Extract part of keys from JSON column
I have this table column:

I want the trailing numbers retrieved from the key names and stored in this manner:



ID




1


2


3


4



I can retrieve it using:
REGEXP_REPLACE((json_each_text(fixtures::json)).key, '.*?(\d+)', '\1')::int as ID

But I want it retrieved differently without '.*?(\d+)', '\1')

Which DBMS are you using? The presence of the call to function json_each_text implies heavily this is Postgres, but please tag it affirmatively.

Yes you are correct. I have tagged it. Thanks

"I want it retrieved differently" Can you elaborate on what exactly is the specific problem in this case? What isn't meeting your requirements in your current approach that you're looking to change it? Are you looking for a different pattern, or something that doesn't rely on regular expressions at all?

Please provide a table definition as CREATE TABLE script, and sample data as text, never as image. And always your version of Postgres.


Use json_object_keys() instead of extracting key:value pairs then only keeping .key field.
You can extract only the matching subexpression with regexp_substr() instead of matching the whole thing, then replacing it with the parenthesized part.
$ matches the end of the input string.

Demo at db<>fiddle:
create table your_table(fixtures) as values
('{ "fixture_1":"fixture1"
   ,"fixture_2":"fixture2"
   ,"fixture_321":"fixture321"}');

select regexp_substr(json_object_keys(fixtures::json),'(\d+)$')::int as "ID"
from your_table;




ID




1


2


321




As pointed out by Erwin Brandstetter, if you can rely on the underscore _ being always in front of the number like you showed, the simpler split_part() will perform way better: 3x on 10k rows with up to a 100 fixtures each.
To make sure you're always getting the part after the last underscore (handle both _fixture_7 and fixture_7 as well as f_i_x_t_u_r_e_7), you can use negative subscript/position:
select split_part(jsonb_object_keys(fixtures), '_', -1)::int as "ID"
from your_table;




Or substring(json_object_keys(fixtures::json) from '_(\d+)$')::integer, basically the same with an extra _ as  an anchor.

json_object_keys() is simpler and faster for the case than json_each_text(), Zegarek already provided that.
split_part() is simpler and faster for the case (always one _ as separator before the dangling number) than employing regular expressions. You seem to be asking for a solution without regexp: "without '.*?(\d+)', '\1')".
split_part(json_object_keys(fixtures::json), '_', 2)::int AS id

See:

Split comma separated column data into additional columns

Also, fixtures should probably be type json or jsonb to begin with, making the cast ::json unnecessary.
You are aware that this produces a single set from all top-level object keys in all rows, with possible duplicates? You may want to throw in DISTINCT:
SELECT DISTINCT split_part(json_object_keys(fixtures), '_', 2)::int AS id
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;

Or you may want IDs per row (no dupes per row if your key names are consistent):
SELECT t.id, k.ids
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ARRAY (SELECT split_part(json_object_keys(t.fixtures), '_', 2)::int)
  ) k(ids) ON true;

fiddle
Related:

Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?
What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?

